# Model for an eCommerce shop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create an eCommerce shop. My main idea is every user can create their own store, and I have models like this:

model/user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :store
end
```

model/store.rb:

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user   
   has_many :products
end
```

model/product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :store
end
```

I don't know if the relationships between these models is good enough or I should modify them. And for further update, if  user_1 add product sold by user_2 to his cart, I don't know what will the relationship be between these two users

Answer (score 1):

Your models don't have a relationship between `User` and `Product` yet.

You can say `User` `has_many: :products`
and `Product` `has_one: :user` but this relationship would be incomplete.

The `user-product` relationship needs to be done through the `store`. That's where [`has_many: through`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) comes in handy.

`User` `has_many :products, through: :store`

`Product` `has_one :user, through: :store`